# Namespace Processing in XML

Tags: xml

Can anybody tell me what exactly does one mean by **namespace processing**. I have read everything about xml namespaces, and xml schemas, but haven't been able find anywhere what does the above term means.

I believe its a name for some normal task, but I'd like to be sure what it means.

Thanks.

Comment: I answered below, but processing is such a general term, that my answer could be out of context.  Where did you find reference to it?

Comment: I am creating an android app which will work as a RSS reader. There's a method named (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#setFeature(java.lang.String, boolean)) setFeature. One of the parameters is `FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation on `FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES` says

> This feature determines whether the parser processes namespaces.

"Namespace processing" in this context just means "expecting that an XML file is going to use the semantics defined in the [XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) standard, and parsing accordingly."

Here's the deal. If a file is supposed to be parsed with namespace processing then `<foo:bar/>` is supposed to an empty element named `bar` in the namespace associated with the prefix `foo`. If the same file is supposed to be parsed without namespace processing then `<foo:bar/>` is an empty element named `foo:bar`. (XML 1.0 does not mandate namespaces and makes the colon a valid element name.) A document consisting of this:

```
<foo:bar/>
```

Can be valid or invalid depending on whether namespace processing is off or on.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  Via IBM, XML namespace processing

> allows the use of multiple XML schemas definitions within an XML
>   document or building a grammar from several different schemas, by
>   providing a way to resolve name conflicts between the schemas.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r2mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wpg.entadv.doc/config/mapping/rxml_namesp.html

Comment: That is not xml processing, that's the concept of xml namespace, explaining why it's important and why it is used. I read that document before posting my question.